# HIDE/SHOW Markers

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show, leaflet

I am developing a website that has a mapping and i am using leaflet. Now im on the part that i will hide /show markers that i made.

below is my code finding the image that i want and use it as a marker

```
var Icon1 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'legends/fire.GIF',
     iconSize:     [170, 120], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [100, 120], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    popupAnchor:  [-7, -80] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
```

the other one below is my code when putting the mark on the map.

```
function mark()
{
if (select1.value === "Fire"){
var note = document.getElementById('note');
var datepick = document.getElementById('demo1');
var timepick = document.getElementById('timepick');
        map.on('click', function(e){
        var marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng,{icon: Icon1});
        marker.bindPopup("</a><br><strong>FIRE</strong></br><strong>Date:</strong>"+datepick.value+"</br><strong>Time:</strong>"+timepick.value+"</br><strong>Address:</strong>"+note.value+"<strong><br><strong>Suspect Sketch</strong><br><a href=legends/suspect.jpg rel=lightbox><img src = legends/suspect.jpg height=100 width = 100/>").addTo(map);

        marker.on('dragend');
        });
```

This is my code in hiding the marker.

```
script type="text/javascript">

function closure(marker){
var checkbox = document.getElementById("chbx")

   $(chbx).click(function(){
      if(map.hasLayer(marker)){
        window.alert("I want to hide the marker");
      }
      window.alert("I want to show the marker");
   })
}
</script>
```

This is just what i wanted.
1.Add A marker on the map
2.Hide/Show the marker in the map
3.Make this happen during run time or when i try it.

I try everything but still nothing happens.
What is the right thing to do to call my hide/show function in checkbox?

Comment: sorry, for improper usage i already change it, i hope someone will help me with this because im still questionable about this part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:
Define a function which takes marker as its argument, and with jQuery create a function to toggle the visibility of the layer:

```
function closure(marker){
   $('#yourcheckbox id').click(function(){
      if(map.hasLayer(marker)){
         map.removeLayer(marker)
      }
      else {map.addLayer(marker)}
   })
}
```

Than, inside the click event of the map, add the closure function:

```
map.on('click', function(e){
    marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
    closure (marker)
})
```

Comment: thank you for the code, i will try this, anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: <script>
function closure(marker){
   $(marker).click(function(){
      if(map.hasLayer(marker)){
         map.removeLayer(marker)
      }
      else {map.addLayer(marker)}
   })
}
document.getElementById(marker);
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="marker"> 
 
I dont know, Am I right?

Comment: Its not working, i dont now why. i put a mark in the map then click my checkbox but the marker not show/hide

Answer (score 0):

With `.addTo(map)` should works.

However, you can use `addLayer` and `removeLayer` for add/remove markers:

```
var marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng,{icon: Icon1});
marker.bindPopup('<div>Hello World</div>');

//add the marker to the map
map.addLayer(marker);

//remove the marker from the map
map.removeLayer(marker);
```

I assume that you have created the `map`

Comment: yes indeed i already created the map, i hope it helps, thank you so much, i will check this after i try it. but i hope it works on my goal, because my goal is that marker filtering check/unchecked hide show

Comment: I dont know how it works? I just want to initiate this code inside a checkbox so anytime marker that has been place on the map will hide/show everytime i check/uncheck

Comment: can you make jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases for hiding markers we may use such method, may be.

```
marker._icon.style.display = 'none';

if (value._popup._isOpen)
{
  marker.closePopup();
}
```

For show markers after hiding.

```
marker._icon.style.display = '';
```